# Worklight 6.2 - HTML files being modified by build

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I'm developing a SPA that uses RequireJS to load HTML template fragments.  During the build, it seems WL 6.2 is parsing and trying to turn those into fully valid HTML documents.  For example, a foo.html file that looks like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <% if (bar) { %>
        <div class="baz">Message</div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

is becoming something like this:

```
<html><body><div class="foo">
    <_ if="if" bar="bar" _="_">
        <div class="baz">Message</div>
    <_ _="_">
</_></_></div>
</body></html>
```

Minification and concatenation are turned off in the build configuration, and I didn't see any other likely settings.

How can I turn off this modification?

Comment: Worklight does parse and make modifications to the main page of a hybrid application when the app is built, and it is expected to be valid HTML5.  It is not possible to turn this off.  Other HTML pages in the application are not touched.  In my experimentation, if I put things in the main HTML page that look like the above, they're modified, but not exactly in the way your example shows.  Would need more data about exactly what you're doing to provide better information.

Comment: In particular, in my test, "<% if (bar) { %>" simply becomes "&lt;if (bar) { %&gt;"

Comment: @patbarron This is a project that's been migrated from WL 6.1.  It contains Android and iPhone environments, although I'm seeing this particular problem with the mobilewebapp.  I'm personally seeing this on Windows, but a colleague sees something similar on Mac.  What data can I provide to help debug this?

Comment: Please add JDK version (+vendor) and Windows version. It will help us to re-produce

Comment: @asselin Could you try creating a new project "testProj" and new Hybrid App "testApp". then put foo.html with the content of the template inside apps/testApp/common/. I tried this and after a buid+deploy, I can see in testApp/iphone/native/www/default/foo.html is not changed. I did it with a clean install of Eclipse kepler + Worklight 6.2.0.00 + Mac 10.9.4

Comment: This was actually the server that was making the change, not the build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM fixed this in APAR PI22635 (WHEN DEVELOPING A SPA (SINGLE-PAGE APP) IN WORKLIGHT 6.2, THE SERVER IS CONVERTING HTML FRAGMENTS INTO A GARBLED INVALID OUTPUT), which is part of iFix Worklight v6.2.0.0 InterimFix 201408011709

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very similar to a bug currently identified in WL 6.2 (APAR PI21516)

IBM customers can see the APAR page at: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PI21516

The bug has been already fixed and is queued to be delivered on the next iFix, which should happen soon. You can contact your IBM representative who can assist you in getting prior access to this iFix if needed.

I would suggest that you try this new version and, if the problem is not solved, register a PMR with the IBM support team for further investigation.

Also please keep this question updated so we and others can follow the problem resolution.

Comment: OK, sounds like a plan.  Thanks for the help.